# Play json transformers map optional field

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I have the following play framework 2.3 json transformer

```
val transAddress = (
  (__ \ 'address \ 'line1).json.copyFrom( (__ \ 'line1).json.pick ) and
  (__ \ 'address \ 'line2).json.copyFrom( (__ \ 'line2).json.pick ) and
  (__ \ 'address \ 'line3).json.copyFrom( (__ \ 'line3).json.pick ) and

  (__ \ 'address \ 'line4).json.copyFrom( (__ \ 'line4).json.pick ) and

  (__ \ 'address \ 'postcode).json.copyFrom( (__ \ 'postcode).json.pick ) reduce
)
```

So this:

```
{
    line1: "My Street",
    line2: "My Borough",
    line3: "My Town",
    line4: "My County"
}
```

Should transform to this:

```
{
    address: {
        line1: "My Street",
        line2: "My Borough",
        line3: "My Town",
        line4: "My County"
    }
}
```

My problem is that in the source json model, line4 is optional, so i only want to map it to address.line4 optionally as well. So:

```
{
    line1: "My Street",
    line2: "My Borough",
    line3: "My Town"
}
```

Should also transform to this:

```
{
    address: {
        line1: "My Street",
        line2: "My Borough",
        line3: "My Town"
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to do this with these transformers, and can find no similar problem after a lot of googling.

Thanks!
Nic

Comment: It would help if you'd include a sample of the JSON, and what it should be transformed to.

Comment: Thanks, ive added examples

Comment: @nfvindaloo does my answer work for you?

Answer (score -1):

Use `Option` with `readNullable`

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._
case class Address(line1: String, line2: String, line3: String, line4: Option[String])

object Address {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Address] = (
      (JsPath \ "line1").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "line2").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "line3").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "line4").readNullable[String]
    )(Address.apply _)
}
```

Comment: Its similar but what I need is a transformer like this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonTransformers Specifically its the copyFrom method that does not like readNullable

Comment: Doesn't address the question, which is about the "transformers". Going back and forth to a case class is not what is asked here.